# how to generate this type of data?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy

I need to generate a object like this:

```
ndarray: [[1  2    3]]
```

so I tried the following:

```
test = [[1, 2, 3]]
```

but this is not the same. So I tried:

```
test = [[1 2 3]]
```

but this is not valid.

How to generate it?

Comment: It looks like you need to use numpy, although the format doesn't even look like numpy to me.

Comment: What are the properties of `[[1  2    3]]`? Is it a list with three elements? Do the different number of spaces mean anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
In [20]: import numpy as np

In [21]: test = np.array([[1,2,3]])

In [22]: test
Out[22]: array([[1, 2, 3]])

In [23]: print(test)
[[1 2 3]]

In [24]: test.shape
Out[24]: (1, 3)

In [26]: type(test)
Out[26]: <type 'numpy.ndarray'>
```

Comment: `ndarray` is the primary class provided by numpy.

Answer (score 0):

As you did is its to create a list, but not a numpy array. Besides the @unutbu suggestion, also with numpy you can do it as follows:

```
In[1]: test = np.arange(1,4,1)
In[2]: test
Out[2]: array([1, 2, 3])
```